# Java 8 - how sum many fields into a dto?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a class Item like this:

```
class Item {  
    private long id;  
    private BigDecimal value1;  
    private BigDecimal value2;  
    private BigDecimal value3;  
}
```

Then I have a list with many itens, I want to know the sum of each of the values:

So, I know I could do something like

```
BigDecimal v1 = list.stream().map(Item::value1).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

However, this way I would need to do the same for each value, I'd like to know if there's some way of summing each attribute into only one Dto like:

```
class TotalItem {  
    private BigDecimal value1;  
    private BigDecimal value2;  
    private BigDecimal value3;  
}  

TotalItem t = list.stream().map(???).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Is this possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to create new class for stats.

Comment: Each values separately, meaning 3 sum values for result or three different values into the same sum?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test it but I think that you can implement add function on `Item` like:

```
public Item add(Item other) {
   Item newItem = new Item(this.value1 + other.value1,
              this.value2 + other.value2,
              this.value3 + other.value3);

   return newItem;
}
```

and then do:

```
Item t = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, Item::add);
```

Comment: That will not compile: `Item` is not assignable to `TotalItem`.

Comment: That's easily solvable. Either don't use TotalItem because it is exactly the same, or implement "toTotalItem()"

Comment: Why would an `Item` care about possibility of converting it to `TotalItem`? This is violation of SRP.

Comment: Is it necessary to use TotalItem to represent an aggregation?

Comment: If you want to use "reduce" you have to map List<Item> to List<TotalItem> first (and that's not pretty). No working around it.

Comment: @AlonSegal which the item id belongs to when reducing?you must introduce another class `Value` to OP.and before reducing you need map each  Item to Value,e.g:`items.map(Value::from).reduce(Value::add).orElse(Value.ZERO)`.

Comment: Map to TotalItem then there's no id anymore.

Comment: @holi-java When you're doing aggregation on database rows (something like `select sum(some_db_column) from table` ), where are the id's? it's the same here.

Comment: @AlonSegal it look like works fine, but have many problems.because when a client code using Item, they  think that an item holding an id, and want to operate it on, but they found they can't,so it is not a real item.

Comment: @holi-java that is acceptable. But I think that the owner of the question will not agree to implement a conversion method on `Item` (as I already proposed it).

Comment: @AlonSegal he already having a value type `TotalItem`,that @BalázsMáriaNémeth has been said.

Comment: @holi-java I already offered to implement `toTotalItem()` on `Item` before, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @AlonSegal BalázsMáriaNémeth has said is TotalItem depends Item,Item don't depends TotalItem.so you can adding a factory method in TotalItem class,but you needn't add an instance method toTotalItem() method on Item, because Item does not depends on TotalItem.

Comment: One suggestion is to use an interface to represent an object that has 3 values. Then you can reduce items down to aggregate items.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following way?

```
TotalItem t = new TotalItem();

list.stream().forEach(item -> {
   t.value1+ = item.value1;
   t.value2+ = item.value2;
   t.value3+ = item.value3;
});
```

Comment: This one is bad because it has side effects

Comment: @maxpovver What side-effects?

Comment: in foreach it changes variable outside of that foreach. it can get broken if some new code will be added ofter total item creation

Comment: Why would you add code that would change `TotalItem` and break it? You obviously don't want to do that. If a solution is simple, use it. Don't complicate it by trying to account for improbable anomalies.

Comment: This is just a shortcut for doing a regular enhanced for loop. I can understand the concern for side-effects inside of a map() or reduce() method, but forEach() naturally seems to be intended for purposes such as this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that Item/TotalItem are very large objects, which would make writing a `toTotalItem` and a `summarise(TotalItem,TotalItem)` by hand a large and laborious job. One that is completely boilerplate and easy to get wrong.

Change the data structure to be a list or map - This makes summarisation simpler, at the cost of readability of the code and type safety.

Use reflection to iterate over the [fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--).

```
TotalItem toTotalItem(Item item) {
    Field[] targetFields = TotalItem.class.getFields();
    Collection<Field> sourceFields = Item.class.getFields().stream()
       .filter(x=>fieldNameIsIn(x, targetFields)           
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

    TotalItem returnItem = new TotalItem();
    for(Field field : sourceFields) {
        toTargetField(field, targetFields).set(returnItem, (BigDecimal) field.get(item));
    }
    return returnItem;
}
boolean fieldNameIsIn(Field sourceField, Field[] targetFields) // exercise for the reader
Field toTargetField(Field sourceField, Field[] targetFields) // exercise for the reader
```

This code above is not neat, but should show the concept. The same concept could be used to summarise.

This reduces the amount of code you need to write, but at the cost of runtime speed. Reflection is also hard to get right and magic (which some developers do not like).

The faster option would be a custom annotation which adds in summarisation. However this would be large chunk of work. If you have a large number of objects that need this, then it may make sense. Like reflection it is hard to get right and magic (which some developers do not like). Luckily you do not need a build step as Javac supports annotation processing natively.

Comment: (This is in reply to a deleted comment complaining about the solution)

I've seen cases when the Item and TotalItem were very large. So the summing of two of them was a large, completely dull, easy to get wrong boilerplate code.  Automating that (like Apache Commons does with toString/equals) makes sense.
It needs to be a lot better than the code written above though. That is example code to show the concept.
I had a play with the annotation solution at the time but never finished off the prototype.

Comment: What I meant is that reflection is sometimes voodoo and I prefer to be more explicit. I'm not saying that this solution doesn't work.

Comment: It is. Definitely. 
But wrapped up in a well tested library (like Apache Commons toString/Equals) it works very well. I personally hate boiler plate code. We have computers to do boiler plate for us. So why not use them.

Personally I think the custom annotation approach (like Project Lombok) would be the right solution to this problem. A @Summarizable annotation and some annotations on how to summarize the fields.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by JDK way of doing similar operations. Namely, I'll be referencing [DoubleSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) class.

First, we define a holder for information about BigDecimals we'll be collecting:

```
public class BigDecimalSummaryStats {
  private long count;
  private MathContext mc;
  private BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
  private BigDecimal max;
  private BigDecimal min;

  public BigDecimalSummaryStats(MathContext mathCtx) {
    mc = requireNonNull(mathCtx);
  }

  public Supplier<BigDecimalSummaryStats> supplier(MathContext ctx) {
    return () -> new BigDecimalSummaryStats(ctx);
  }

  public void accept(BigDecimal value) {
    requireNonNull(value);
    count++;
    sum = sum.add(value, mc);
    min = min.min(value);
    max = max.max(value);
  }

  public void combine(BigDecimalSummaryStats other) {
    requireNonNull(other);
    count += other.count;
    sum = sum.add(other.sum, mc);
    min = min.min(other.min);
    max = max.max(other.max);
  }

  public long getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  public BigDecimal getSum() {
    return sum;
  }
  public BigDecimal getMax() {
    return max;
  }
  public BigDecimal getMin() {
    return min;
  }
  public BigDecimal getAverage() {
    long c = getCount();
    return c == 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : getSum().divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(c), mc);
  }
}
```

This will provide with nice general utility suitable for collecting summary from arbitrary sequences of BigDecimal values.

Then, we can define a Summary class for our Item:

```
public class ItemSummaryStats {
  private BigDecimalSummaryStats value1;
  private BigDecimalSummaryStats value2;
  private BigDecimalSummaryStats value3;
  // ... other fields as needed
  public ItemSummaryStats(MathContext math) {
    value1 = new BigDecimalSummaryStats(math);
    value2 = new BigDecimalSummaryStats(math);
    value3 = new BigDecimalSummaryStats(math);
  }

  public void accept(Item item) {
    value1.accept(item.value1);
    value2.accept(item.value2);
    value3.accept(item.value3);
    // ... other fields as needed
  }
  public void combine(ItemSummaryStats other) {
    value1.combine(other.value1);
    value2.combine(other.value2);
    value3.combine(other.value3);
  }

  public TotalItem get(
     Function<BigDecimalSummaryStats, BigDecimal> v1Mapper,
     Function<BigDecimalSummaryStats, BigDecimal> v2Mapper,
     Function<BigDecimalSummaryStats, BigDecimal> v3Mapper) {

     TotalItem t = new TotalItem();
     t.value1 = v1Mapper.get(value1);
     t.value2 = v2Mapper.get(value2);
     t.value3 = v3Mapper.get(value3);
     return t;
  }

  public TotalItem getSum() {
    return get(BigDecimalSummaryStats::getSum,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getSum,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getSum);
  }
  public TotalItem getAverage() {
    return get(BigDecimalSummaryStats::getAverage,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getAverage,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getAverage);
  }
  public TotalItem getMin() {
    return get(BigDecimalSummaryStats::getMin,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getMin,
               BigDecimalSummaryStats::getMin);
  }
  //.... other methods basically all the same. You get the idea.
}
```

And finally we use this goodness like this:

```
TotalItem totals = list.stream().collect(
      Collector.of(() -> new ItemStatsSummary(MathContext.DECIMAL64),
                   ItemStatsSummary::accept,
                   ItemStatsSummary::combine,
                   ItemStatsSummary::getSum)
    )
```

Cons of this approach:

1. Slightly longer development time than adhoc solutions.

Are far outweighed by the pros, or at least I'm convinced of it:

1. Follows separation of concerns principle: Item Stats are not actually concerned how to collect summary of specific field: they can trust that BigDecimalSummary works
2. Testable: Each part can be tested in its own suite. You can trust that every field will work the same since they use the same API.
3. Flexible: `get(Function...)` method exposes a big list of possibilities: you can collect sum of first field, an averabe of second and min of third if needed.